# Installing VM NIC with Intel diver e1000

Tags: linux-device-driver, linux-from-scratch

I have installed Ubuntu Linux image in a VMware virtual box. Then I added three NIC interfaces. They all have Intel e1000 as the driver when I validated with ethtool command.

Then I installed another Custom Linux image in a VMware virtual box. Then I added three NIC interfaces as earlier. They all have pcnet from AMD as the driver when I validated with ethtool command.

```
lspci | grep -i net
02:01:0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices AMD 79c978 PCnet32 Lance 

(rev 10)
02:02:0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices AMD 79c978 PCnet32 Lance 

(rev 10)
02:03:0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices AMD 79c978 PCnet32 Lance 

(rev 10)

/etc/udev/rules file
#PCI device 0x1022:0x2000 (pcnet32)
SUBSYSTEM=="net" ACTION=="add" Drivers"?*" ATTR{address}==Mac address
ATTR{dev_id}="0x0" ATTR{type}==1 KERNEL=="eth*" Name="eth0"

#PCI device 0x1022:0x2000 (pcnet32)
SUBSYSTEM=="net" ACTION=="add" Drivers"?*" ATTR{address}==Mac address
ATTR{dev_id}="0x0" ATTR{type}==1 KERNEL=="eth*" Name="eth1"

#PCI device 0x1022:0x2000 (pcnet32)
SUBSYSTEM=="net" ACTION=="add" Drivers"?*" ATTR{address}==Mac address
ATTR{dev_id}="0x0" ATTR{type}==1 KERNEL=="eth*" Name="eth2"

/sbin/modprobe -c | grep pcnet32
alias pci:v00001022d00002000sv*sd*bc*sc*i* pcnet32
alias pci:v00001022d00002001sv*sd*bc*sc*i* pcnet32
alias pci:v00001023d00002000sv*sd*bc02sc00i* pcnet32
```

When I see modprobe entries in Custom Linux I also see e1000 entries.

It would be great to know if there is a way to configure NIC using e1000 in custom Linux. I see some reference on “compatible” entries and mod alias entries. As I am coming from web application development, I am not sure how to make use of these references and steps so that I get NIC that supports DPDK Intel(e1000) in custom Linux.

As per my understanding, once the device added in the system, OS will check in mod alias based on compatible entry and load right driver. I am not sure whether I need to check some settings in Custom linux compilation

Would appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: You should be able to configure the virtual NIC device types connected to your virtual machine using your VM software.

Comment: There are errors in your udev rules, `Drivers"?*"` should be `Drivers=="?*"`, and I'm *pretty sure* you can't set attributes, `ATTR{dev_id}="0x0"` should be `ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0"` ...most examples delimit with commas, but maybe that's not required.

Comment: have you configured VMware virtual box to use `intel e1000` instead of `pcnet from AMD`. based on the logs from guest OS it looks like you have not updated `lspci | grep -i net`. Please correct NIC type on host which emulates the NIC on guest.

Comment: In VM Player, I got intel e1000 by default in Ubuntu where as in custom Linux it's pcnet32. Then I added ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000" in vmx file. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Added the following line in vm player vmx file.
`ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"

It solved the issue
`